# Is it possible add shortcut keys to change Wrap tabs settings?

Tags: visual-studio-code

is it possible, add the shortcuts keys to quick change Wrap Tabs settings?

[image]

[image]

Comment: What you suggest would be cool. So far I'm having them wrapped and if I want to see them individually I do `Ctrl + Tab` to navigate through them and I set `openEditorAtIndex1` 2, 3, 4 etc assigned to Ctrl + 1, 2, 3 ...

Answer (score 0):

You could use the extension [Settings Toggle](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=z0al.settings-toggle)

If you call the commands: `settings-toggle.toggle` and `settings-toggle.toggle-workspace` by key binding you get the pick list to select the setting and change the value.

I have created a [feature request](https://github.com/z0al/settings-toggle/issues/58) to allow arguments to bypass the pick list.

```
  {
    "key": "ctrl+i w",
    "command": "settings-toggle.toggle-workspace",
    "args": {
      "action": "toggle",
      "setting": "workbench.editor.wrapTabs"
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you, sorry, but i not understand, how and where can i to create this fearture request? In settings.json?

Comment: Currently the extension does **not** use key binding arguments, the feature request is to get it fixed, until then you have to search the setting from the pick list

Comment: ok, understand. I use now with ctrl + , and command "wrap tabs". It's ok, faster as just check and uncheck. 
Is it possible to make the last command be allway on top, just like the by Command Palette?

Comment: `make the last command be allway on top` : which last command?